# Azure Data Factory Linked service to Synapse Serverless Pool through Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Am trying to connect to Synapse Serverless Pool using Service Principal but getting below error in my Azure Data Factory Pipeline.

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'xxxxx-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net', Database: 'synapse_od', User: ''. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'., SqlErrorNumber=18456,Class=14,State=1,
Activity ID: 2516df76-0215-4f27-990d-3c4654a07704.
**This may happen if your data source only allows secured connections. If that's the case, please use a VNet integration runtime**.
```

But can happily connect using SQL Authentication.

Service Principal been granted Contributor role on Synapse.

Any clues!!!!

Comment: oh.. forgot a step to create user in synapse serverless pool for external provider and assign relevant db role.  All good now.

Comment: hope this will help documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#service-principal-authentication

Answer (score 0):

After I do following steps. Linked service with Service principal Authentication type works fine.

```sql
CREATE USER [ad_user_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;


EXEC sp_addrolemember db_owner, [ad_user_name];
```